# mysql.rds_history query locked for 70 seconds

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, performance, slow-log

```
SELECT  count(*)
    from  mysql.rds_history
    WHERE  action = 'disable set master'
    GROUP BY  action_timestamp,called_by_user,action,mysql_version,
        master_host,master_port,master_user,master_log_file ,
        master_log_pos,master_ssl
    ORDER BY  action_timestamp
    LIMIT  1
```

This query appears in my slow log as locked for 110 seconds at the exact moment I am doing an ETL query that usually takes ~10 seconds.  Intermittently the ETL job stalls for 90+ seconds which seems to correlate to this query that Amazon seems to be running on my T2.micro instance. Is there anything I can do to prevent my query from being affected by this?

Comment: Is Amazon doing some sort of maintenance at that moment?

Comment: No, that is scheduled for a specified 30 min window each week.

Comment: I upgraded mysql version and have never seen this since ( in case anyone else stumbles across this)